# How can I map a relative path in weblogic to virtual path?

Tags: java, spring, weblogic, virtual-path

I am uploading some documents from my application in

`C:\oracle\MiddlewareWeblogic\user_projects\domains\base_domain\uploads`

because from my code ,

```
File f=new File(".");
f.getCanonicalPath();
```

returns me the above path automatically (don't know how !)

I have created one folder in base_domain called 'uploads' and in it I upload user files, etc

However I want some web-based path to uploads folder , like mapping 'uploads' to , say, `http://localhost:7001/<my-context-root>/UPLOADS/userdoc.pdf`

Something like

```
<wls:virtual-directory-mapping>
   <local-path>C:\oracle\MiddlewareWeblogic\user_projects\domains\base_domain\uploads</local-path>
   <url-pattern>/UPLOADS/*</url-pattern>
   <url-pattern>*.pdf</url-pattern>
</wls:virtual-directory-mapping>
```

I tried it and its different variations, but for some really strange reason it doesn't work for me :(
In my weblogic.xml file, all tags have wls: prefix, Thats how my senior made it for me.

**Can anyone please help. I would be really grateful**